# Java build process that prevents references to forbidden classes

Tags: java, eclipse, validation, ant, build

I have to adhere to coding guidelines that prevent using some JDK classes and methods.
I'd like to have a plugin for Ant or Eclipse that I can run to check if my code is compliant. 
I would be supplying it with a blacklist (or maybe a whitelist).

Answer (score 2):

Try [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/). It has a plethora of options that you can enforce on developers.

Comment: +1. Their `IllegalImport` module seems to fit the bill, at least on the per-class level.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more involved is using [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/), but there are a lot of 'rules' you can program into that. See [this blog post of mine](http://wimdeblauwe.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/using-aspectj-and-annotations-to-document-framework-pollution-in-the-domain-model/) for an example on how to use AspectJ for a very custom coding guideline rule enforcement.

Comment: I agree, AspectJ is absolutely the way to go (+1)

Comment: Can I use this approach to forbid references to say java.util.Hashtable (a class whose source I cannot annotate)?

Comment: Sure, using the [call](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html) pointcut.

Answer (score 0):

[PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) could do that. I am not sure it out-of-the box, but implementing such a rule is not too hard to do. The [import-rules](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/imports.html) could be a start. PMD plugins exist for Eclipse, ant and other IDEs and build tools.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers, there is another alternative for achieving this. Define a custom SecurityManager. See [checkPackageAccess()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkPackageAccess%28java.lang.String%29) for more details.

Comment: That would be at runtime, right? I need a compile-time check.

Comment: You are right, SecurityManager needs to be set for checking the permissions. Until java allows classes to be compiled at runtime (I read about this being incorporated into JDK 7, not sure where), this is going to be an Achilles heel. However, the ability to enforce policies on code which you can not see (third party code) is a big thing.